# How to filter with text matching?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to make a query in mongodb and node which filters with matching text.

I tried to take the parameter sent and concatenate with slashes at the beginning and at the end but it doesn't work.

```
const {filterTerm} = req.body;
    const slash1 = "/";
    const slash2 = "/";

    const term = slash1.concat(filterTerm);
    const finalTerm = term.concat(slash2);

    console.log(finalTerm);

    Bookings.find({$or: [{email: finalTerm}, {phone: finalTerm}]})
        .exec((err, docs) => {
            res.json(docs);
        });`
```

Comment: you're looking for `$regex`

Comment: I am new to mongo like 2 days old. I want to make what in sql is done for example: %searchTerm%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RegExp

```
const finalTerm = term.concat(slash2);
Bookings
  .find({$or: [{email: new RegExp(finalTerm, 'gi') }, {phone: new RegExp(finalTerm, 'gi') }]})
  .exec((err, docs) => {
      res.json(docs);
  });
```